# Is this a linear functional?

Tags: functional-analysis

$A$ is a normed vector space and $B$ is a closed subspace of A.

Let $\phi \in V^*$

For $a \in A$,   $ \phi (a) = inf${$|| (a - b)|| :$ for all $b \in B $ }

I need this to be true for my argument for the proof.

But I don't think this is true.

Since if *A* = **R** and B = [1, 2]

Then $ \phi (4)$ = 2

And $ \phi (0)$ = 1

But then $\phi (4)$ is not 3

Is it right?

Answer (score 1):

B is not a subspace in the example you gave. It is not a linear functional, try to decompose a vector $v$ into a sum of two vectors, one in B and the other in the orthogonal complement of B: $v=b+\bar{b}$. Then $\phi(v)$ will be $||\bar{b}||$.